# How to get pan gesture to move a label horizontally and disappear?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I want to get the same effect as here:

[image]

I have set a UIPanGestureRecognizer and I can move the label around, this is how I did it:

```
- (IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
    recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x,
                                         recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];
}
```

This is the method in the view controller, of course I added a pan gesture object to the xib file and set the proper connections.

And I also know the method that get it to disappear:

```
[self.homeLabel removeFromSuperview];
```

But how can I make the same effect as in the gif?

I also have an image property for the v sign called vSignImage.

I want to be able to move it only horizontally to the right, make the v sign slide in from the left after I moved the label x px to the right, and when I release my finger I want the label to disappear.

Please help :)

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use any kind of gesture recognizer. Just put the label in a little horizontal-only scroll view. Now the user can only slide the label horizontally. Now use the delegate to detect / govern what happens as the user slides the label. This is how swipe-to-delete works in Apple's Mail program, for example.

Comment: the first part on the solution I got and thank you for that, its giving me the behavior I wanted, but for the second part, is there a specific delegate method I should use? can you give me a link to the proper info please4? and also how do I get the v sign icn to slid in from the left whenever I scroll? tnx

Comment: for the v sign I think i got it, i just added it to the scroll view and settled its x origin in the xib file to -50 and I get the effect. but is that right?